# Disallow user to perform an update on a field or member of a class and return 405 Method Not Allowed : HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I am working on an api which serves creating,updating,deleting of user settings for an application. My users are of two types

- admin user
- common user

I have a field `public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }` which says whether a common user is allowed to change the setting or not.

Now the question is in which layer i need to validate this and throw the 405 response to the client. Please suggest.

```
private readonly SettingsRepository _SettingsRepository;

[HttpPut("{userid}/settings/{settingName}")]
public IActionResult Put(string userid, [FromBody]Setting setting)
{
    var result = _SettingsRepository.Update(userid, setting);
    if (result == true)
    {
        return Ok(201);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}

//Updates the existing setting for a user having userid     
public bool Update(string userid, Setting setting)
{
    bool flag = false;
    if (userid == null || setting == null)
    {
        return flag;
    }
    var existing = Profiles.profiles.Where(p => p.UserID.ToLower() == userid.ToLower() && p.Settings.Any(s => s.Name.ToLower() == setting.Name.ToLower())).SelectMany(res => res.Settings).ToList();
    if (existing.Count() > 0)
    {
        existing.ForEach(e =>
        {
            e.Name = setting.Name;
            e.Value = setting.Value;
            e.Type = setting.Type;
            e.Valid = setting.Valid;
            e.ReadOnly = setting.ReadOnly;
            e.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            e.Encrypted = setting.Encrypted;
            e.Enabled = setting.Enabled;
            e.CreatedOn = setting.CreatedOn;
            e.Description = setting.Description;
        });
        FileSerDe.SerializeSettings<IList<Profile>>(Profiles.profiles, System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "seed.txt");
        flag = true;
    }
        return flag;
}

//Profile Entity
public class Profile
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}

//Setting Entity
public class Setting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Encrypted { get; set; }
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks business logic is in repository. so you can put security measure in repository. do that first thing in repository & throw exception on failed.
this will centralize your business logic to single place.

Answer (score 0):

`405 Method not allowed` would be used when the *HTTP* method (e.g. GET or PUT) is specifically not allowed to be used with a given URL, and would apply to *all* users. For something which is permissions-within your application and related to a specific user it would be more accurate to a send a `403 Forbidden` response.

As for the layers, clearly the API Action method is the only one which can return the actual HTTP error code, but since the information that tells you whether the user has permission is held in the database, you could arrange it so that the data layer tells the API layer what the appropriate response should be, perhaps by throwing an exception or by setting a flag on an output parameter to the database method. This would require you to pass information about the current user to the database layer, though, some people think that's unnecessary overhead, unless it's required anyway to record audit data etc.

The alternative is that you could get the API layer to retrieve the relevant data from the database before attempting to run the Update, and make a decision based on that retrieved data, entirely within the API action method. It's really a design decision that is up to you and what suits your application structure. Either way is possible, and, arguably, valid.